# Format data from a table into another formatted table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have 1 table of data that has 3 columns, 1 being a reference number, the other being a version of that reference and a 3rd being the items belonging to that reference.

What I want to do is to display a table that shows 3 columns, 1st being the reference number, the next being the list of items on the version 1 and the list of items on the 'last final version'.

Original data:

| refno | version | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC123 |
| 1 | 1 | XYZ123 |
| 1 | 2 | EFG123 |
| 2 | 1 | UIO123 |
| 2 | 1 | JKL123 |
| 3 | 1 | ABC123 |
| 3 | 2 | ABC123 |
| 3 | 2 | HJF123 |
| 3 | 2 | IKJ123 |
| 3 | 2 | EEK123 |
| 3 | 2 | EEK123 |
| 4 | 1 | GFD123 |
| 4 | 1 | YUI123 |
| 4 | 2 | YUI123 |
| 5 | 1 | TYP123 |
| 6 | 1 | GHS123 |
| 7 | 1 | TEP123 |
| 7 | 1 | SLS123 |
| 7 | 2 | TEP123 |
| 7 | 2 | SLS123 |
| 7 | 2 | AEE123 |
| 7 | 3 | AAL123 |
| 7 | 4 | QEF123 |

How I want it to be formatted:

| refno | Original Item | Final Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123 | EFG123 |
| 1 | XYZ123 |  |
| 2 | UIO123 | UIO123 |
| 2 | JKL123 | JKL123 |
| 3 | ABC123 | ABC123 |
| 3 |  | HJF123 |
| 3 |  | IKJ123 |
| 3 |  | EEK123 |
| 3 |  | EEK123 |
| 4 | GFD123 | YUI123 |
| 4 | YUI123 |  |
| 5 | TYP123 | TYP123 |
| 6 | GHS123 | GHS123 |
| 7 | TEP123 | QEF123 |
| 7 | SLS123 |  |

Any tips on how to do this in SQL (specifically oracle SQL)

Comment: Let's take refno=1 for example. How did you decide that ABC123 is to be shown on the same row as EFG123, and XYZ123 should appear with `null` in the last column? Why not pair XYZ123 with EFG123 and ABC123 with `null`?

Comment: Not sure that matters. The point is that the 2nd column should have the latest version item in it, no matter where it was placed.

Comment: What do you mean by "not sure"? It's your problem, you don't know what the requirement is? Are you saying that the "pairing" of original item and final item, in rows in the output, can be anything we want - the fact that a specific initial item and a corresponding specific final item appear on the same row has no meaning in your real-life problem?

Comment: There is no pairing happening, I want a list in the same table, 2nd column is just a list of the items on the 1st version and the 3rd column is just a list of items on the last version for that ref no. The only thing that connects the first and last version is the refno, not the items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want full self join

```
select coalesce(a.refno, b.refno) refno, a.item OriginalItem, b.item FinalItem
from(
   select * 
   from t 
   where version = 1
) a
full join(
  select * 
  from (
     select *, rank() over(partition by refno order by version DESC) rn 
     from t 
     where version > 1
  ) t
  where rn=1
) b
on a.refno=b.refno 
order by coalesce(a.refno, b.refno), a.item, b.item
```

Returns

```
refno   OriginalItem    FinalItem
1   ABC123  EFG123
1   XYZ123  EFG123
2   JKL123  
2   UIO123  
3   ABC123  ABC123
3   ABC123  EEK123
3   ABC123  EEK123
3   ABC123  HJF123
3   ABC123  IKJ123
4   GFD123  YUI123
4   YUI123  YUI123
5   TYP123  
6   GHS123  
7   SLS123  QEF123
7   TEP123  QEF123
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, not quite there, so the last final version could also be a version 1 if there are no further version so the 2nd column would then need to show items from version 1, at the moment these would be blank? Also i am getting the same value for each of the rows, so for example where there are 2 items on v1 but only 1 item on v2 the i need to show only 1 of them values and have the next row as blank (not show that item twice.

Comment: Then the second of two `3 NULL EEK123`
`3 NULL EEK123` would be `3 NULL NULL` . Is it really what you want? I mean your desired layout depends on result row ordering. This should be better handled at a client side while the query returns the facts.